# Is an AJAX call cross-domain if only the port is different?

Tags: ajax, security, http, browser

The main page is www.myserver.com:80 and the ajax references www.myserver.com:8081.

The status code is 0 and the text is null.  Is this a cross domain denial?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).